# Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that $\sqrt s$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers, radicals

I need to prove with the Intermediate Value Theorem that $\sqrt s$ exists, where $s > 0$.

My textbook states this definition of the Intermediate Value Theorem: Suppose that $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and let $N$ be any number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, where $f(a)$ is not equal to $f(b)$. Then there exists a number $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = N$.

Some values were already given to me:

- $f(x) = x^2$
- $a = 0$
- $b = s + (1/2)$
- Using the above values, I get $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) = (s+(1/2))^2$

So I'm assuming that I have to choose a value for c that fits the criteria? So if I choose $c = s$, that would be in $(a,b)$ and $f(c) = c^2 = s^2$ would be between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. But does that really prove anything? I guess I just don't understand how the Intermediate Value Thoerem proves the existence of a square root.

Comment: The *Intermediate Value theorem* asserts such a $c$ `exists`, it doesn't say anything on its value, except it's between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with the function $f(x)=x^2-s$. Then $f(0)=-s <0$ and $f\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-s=s^2+\frac{1}{4} >0$. Now use intermediate value theorem to claim that $f$ can be $0$.

Comment: I'm not allowed to choose another $f(x)$, unfortunately.

Comment: @Chris it's doing exactly the same thing but shifting the graph of $f$ down. Look at the other answers to see the solution for your given $f$.

Comment: @Chris in that case egreg's answer would work for you.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use another $f$, then use $g(x)=f(x)-s$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(a)=f(0)=0<s$ and
$$
f(b)=f(s+1/2)=s^2+s+\frac{1}{4}>s
$$
Now apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: So, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there has to exist a $c$ such that $f(c)$ = $s$ because $s$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$?

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok. Is it logical to just say that because $s$ exists, its square root must exist because $s$ is non-negative?

Comment: @Chris The IVT tells you the square root exists: a number $c$ between $0$ and $s+1/2$ such that $c^2=s$.